# Need formula from excel to get the text (organisation name) from the email id

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

I need a formula in excel with if condition.

if the mail id abcd@xyz.com then the result should come as XYZ, if the mail id is abcd@.in.xyz.com then the result should come as XYZ.

result should be XYZ if any of the above mail id is there.

for the first one i got the formula as if mail id is in C2 then the formula is as

```
UPPER(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(MID(C2,FIND("@",C2)+1,LEN(C2)),FIND(".",MID(C2,FIND("@",C2)+2,LEN(C2)))),"."," "))
```

Comment: does it have to be in one formula or can you use helper columns?

Comment: need in a one formula using if

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your email is in `A1` - use this monster:

`=UPPER(MID(A1,IFERROR(FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","#",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))-1)),FIND("@",A1))+1,FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","#",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))))-IFERROR(FIND("#",SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","#",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""))-1)),FIND("@",A1))-1))`

Sample file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/23p3a7hf9pbodiw/OrgEmail.xlsx

Comment: I'm sorry, it doesn't have `IF` - I used `IFERROR` instead..)

Comment: if the mail is abcd@xyz.com after applying this formula i am getting the result as ABCD@XYZ and for abcd@in.xyz.com its the result is coming correct as XYZ.

Comment: @user201373 did you check the sample? it has this e-mail working nice.

Comment: Result not came properly, its 50% results only showing.

Comment: @user201373 could you please provide samples which do not work? 2-3 will be enough.

Comment: @user201373 glad it helped!)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach

`=UPPER(TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"@","."),".",REPT(" ",100)),200),100)))`